# Wait for multiple network calls to finish using Retrofit without RxJava on Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I have multiple network calls which are independent of each other but need some processing once all requests are finished.

I found this [link](https://newfivefour.com/android-rxjava-wait-for-network-calls-finish.html) which explains this using RxJava.

How can we do this without RxJava?

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity or whatever the received data comes, make variables int **numberOfRequestsTotal** and **numberOfRequests** or something. If you know for sure how many requests will be, then you can add number each time any of the requests is finished and check if all requests are finished by checking how many request overall by **numberOfRequestsTotal**. If number will be equal you're done. 
I would implement something like this, but it's much easier and better to do using rxjava.

Comment: It seems using RxJava with the zip functionality is the suggested approach for this most of the time.  However, if you are like me and don't like bloated and unreadable code RxJava is not a very desirable approach.  If you have multiple requests of API calls requiring this you could wrap the functionality in a class with numberOfRequests and totalNumberOfRequests as suggested aboe.  Imo this looks cleaner and more readable for other programmers.